Why is there unplayable (pending) video in my phone when I recorded video correctly?
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy XCover 5. My video is pending file even though I recorded it correctly, and there is a maximum video length on the system.
 
How to solve this problem?

AFAIK, this might happen when the video recording app fails to write the video file to the storage completely (abruptly stopped in the middle of writing), thus resulting in a corrupted video file.

Can i find this folder?

Sorry, I'm not sure what you meant by "this folder". If you meant the corrupted video files, then they're listed on the screenshot that you're currently opening: External storage/AllRecovery/Video and External Storage/DCIM/Camera.

thank you sir.i solved the problem by use mp4 recover tool.thank you sir

Same issue occured in my Samsung F41 .
But in my case it used to happen with the images.
The solution to this is very easy , i simply just clicked one more photo and the glitch was resolved at that instant.
Please try this it should work.
Sorry i cannot comment as i did not meet the reputation requirement.

thank you for your comment!i solved it to use mp4 recover app.thank you
